# Why is this Fizz Buzz generator significantly faster than this Fizz Buzz Iterator class?

Tags: python, performance, iterator, generator, fizzbuzz

After learning about iterator class methods and generators, I tested the performance characteristics of simple Fizz Buzz solutions utilizing each idiom:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('tuple(fizzbuzz.FizzBuzzIterator(10))', 'import fizzbuzz')
13.281935930252075
>>> timeit('tuple(fizzbuzz.fizz_buzz_generator(10))', 'import fizzbuzz')
7.619534015655518
```

According to `timeit` the generator function is about **1¾ times faster** than the iterator class.

My question again: Why is this Fizz Buzz generator significantly faster than this Fizz Buzz Iterator class?

### Fizz Buzz iterator class

```
class FizzBuzzIterator:

    def __init__(self, low, high=None):
        if high is None:
            self.high = low
            self.current = 1
        else:
            self.high = high
            self.current = max(low, 1)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.current > self.high:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            c = self.current
            self.current += 1
            if (c % 5 + c % 3) == 0:
                return 'FizzBuzz'
            elif c % 5 == 0:
                return 'Buzz'
            elif c % 3 == 0:
                return 'Fizz'
            else:
                return str(c)
```

### Fizz Buzz generator function

```
def fizz_buzz_generator(low, high=None):
    if high is None:
        high = low
        cur = 1
    else:
        cur = max(low, 1)
    while cur <= high:
        c = cur
        cur += 1
        if (c % 5 + c % 3) == 0:
            yield 'FizzBuzz'
        elif c % 5 == 0:
            yield 'Buzz'
        elif c % 3 == 0:
            yield 'Fizz'
        else:
            yield str(c)
```

Comment: Thanks to moderator/admin who removed the off-topic answers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because apparently, generators are implemented more efficiently than iterators.

Your first solution has the following interesting characteristics:

1. It uses objects.
2. For an iteration over *n* numbers, *3 + n* methods are called and *2 + 4·n* attributes are accessed, which are both potentially slow operations.
3. Exceptions are used for control flow.

The second solution does none of these, instead it `yield`s which means that the language runtime performs the heavy lifting. As the runtime is usually implemented in C, this can be far more optimized than the very high-level code of your first solution.

Next, you should consider *what* you are actually benchmarking. For a good benchmark you should choose different input sizes *n* and watch how the two solutions compare at different scales.

- For very small *n*, we expect the initalization cost to dominate. This is consistent with your results, as performing a function call is less expensive than creating an object.
- For larger *n*, we expect the features of the algorithm to dominate. As the algorithms are exactly the same, the graphs should have the same shape. But per iteration, the first solution has a much higher cost (four attribute accesses, one method call). The two solutions would then be graphs with slightly different slopes. The exact relation of the per-iteration costs can only be assessed by obtaining a large data set of many timings for many input sizes *n*, and then fitting a function to that data.

Comment: I made some graphs to see how much difference the lines are plotted. http://imgur.com/a/Ehb8U It's amazing the measurable difference. Thanks again for the awesome answer!